# to generate a random colour from 7 options

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to generate a random colour from 7 options. All of the stack overflow posts / tutorials I've found have been ANY random colour. This is the list of the colour :

```
Red = New SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, 255, 0, 0))
White = New SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, 255, 255, 255))
Blue = New SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, 0, 0, 255))
Yellow = New SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, 244, 255, 16))
Green = New SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, 0, 255, 0))
pink = New SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, 255, 16, 22))
Brown = New SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, 120, 37, 37))
```

i want to randomthem to `Label1.foreground` :

```
Label1.Foreground = // I got Stuck at This -,-
```

I try to us a random number generator:

```
Dim randomColour As New Random
```

but I'm Stuck how to do that ... Pls Help Me ....

Comment: Put them all in an array, and pick a random number between 0 and the size of the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use `SolidBrush`.

```
' Create a List
Dim colorList As New List(Of SolidBrush)

' Add colors to it
colorList.Add(New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, 255, 0, 0)))
colorList.Add(New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, 255, 255, 255)))
...

' Create a random instance
Dim rnd = new Random()

' Get a random item from the list between 0 and list count
Dim randomColour = colorList(rnd.Next(0, colorList.Count))

' Assign the color to the label
Me.Label1.ForeColor = randomColour.Color
```

Answer (score 2):

***also you can use button when clicked color change in random***

`Public Class Form1`

```
Dim rnd As New Random

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Me.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, rnd.Next(255), rnd.Next(255), rnd.Next(255))
End Sub
```

`End Class`